# Rails 3 - Form submission issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble getting a for to submit from my show.html.erb page. It is a nested form that sends from /event/1/ticketbuilder/1 to the same page, However, when i submit the form, Ig et a Routing Error (No route matches "/event/1/ticketbuilder/1") even though going to that url directly works just fine.

```
#show.html.erb
<%= form_for @section, :url => event_ticketbuilder_path(@event) do |s| %>
  <%= s.text_field(:name) %> <%= submit_tag("Add Section") %>
<% end %>

#ticketbuilder_controller.rb
class TicketbuilderController < ApplicationController
 def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @section = Section.new
  end
  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event_id])
    @section = @event.sections.build(params[:name])
    if @section.save
      @section = Section.new
    end
    render :action => :show
  end
end
```

When linking directly to the page, it succeeds and i get

```
Started GET "/event/1/ticketbuilder/1" for 206.248.211.83 at Sun Mar 27 15:02:24 -0400 2011
  Processing by TicketbuilderController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
  Event Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Section Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "sections".* FROM "sections" WHERE ("sections".event_id = 1)
  Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE ("locations".section_id = 1)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Rendered ticketbuilder/show.html.erb within layouts/application (52.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 85ms (Views: 56.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

When submitting the form on that page i get

```
Started POST "/event/1/ticketbuilder/1" for 206.248.211.83 at Sun Mar 27 15:02:26 -0400 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/event/1/ticketbuilder/1"):


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

It seems as though I can access the page with the "GET" method but not "POST" I assume this has something to do with the variables being sent through the URL, but I don't have enough knowledge of rails currently to solve this.

```
event_ticketbuilder_index GET    /event/:event_id/ticketbuilder(.:format)          {:controller=>"ticketbuilder", :action=>"index"}
                          POST   /event/:event_id/ticketbuilder(.:format)          {:controller=>"ticketbuilder", :action=>"create"}
  new_event_ticketbuilder GET    /event/:event_id/ticketbuilder/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"ticketbuilder", :action=>"new"}
 edit_event_ticketbuilder GET    /event/:event_id/ticketbuilder/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"ticketbuilder", :action=>"edit"}
      event_ticketbuilder GET    /event/:event_id/ticketbuilder/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"ticketbuilder", :action=>"show"}
                          PUT    /event/:event_id/ticketbuilder/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"ticketbuilder", :action=>"update"}
                          DELETE /event/:event_id/ticketbuilder/:id(.:format)      {:controller=>"ticketbuilder", :action=>"destroy"}
              event_index GET    /event(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"event", :action=>"index"}
                          POST   /event(.:format)                                  {:controller=>"event", :action=>"create"}
                          GET    /event/new(.:format)                              {:controller=>"event", :action=>"new"}
                          GET    /event/:id/edit(.:format)                         {:controller=>"event", :action=>"edit"}
                          GET    /event/:id(.:format)                              {:controller=>"event", :action=>"show"}
                          PUT    /event/:id(.:format)                              {:controller=>"event", :action=>"update"}
                          DELETE /event/:id(.:format)                              {:controller=>"event", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Any help or ideas would greatly appreciated

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see which routes you have available and on which HTTP method they respond. This should give you more insight in the problem.

Comment: Added "rake routes" output for the controller. One issue I see is that the "/1" at the end of "/event/1/ticketbuilder/1" may be causing an issue. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try event_ticketbuilder_index_path for the :url.  You want the create action, which does not have an existing id yet.